How do I create an API request with PATCH method in Neoload as a Code YAML script?
I am trying to convert Neoload GUI request to Neoload-as-a-Code script and it does not support CUSTOM method: PATCH when I upload it on Neoload Web.
This is the request in Neoload GUI:
enter image description here
and this is the YAML code where I am supposed to use it:
      - transaction: name: my_transaction steps: - request:  server: my_server url: my_URL method: PATCH body: | {...
This does not seem to work.
I tried "method: CUSTOM {PATCH}" from what I understood from online help here:
https://github.com/Neotys-Labs/neoload-models/blob/v3/neoload-project/doc/v3/request.md#:~:text=%7Bmethod%2Dname%7D%20for%20CUSTOM%20case
But it does not work.
